# ACLs do not work correctly on cifs Windows share

Tags: mount, kubuntu, windows-7, samba, cifs

Permissions do not function correctly if I mount a Windows 7 share using

```
sudo mount -t cifs //Host/share /mnt/share -o username="Windows User",password="password",iocharset=utf8,uid=user,nobrl,noserverino,cifsacl
```

Specifically, I cannot remove the read or execute bit from a file, but I can change the write bit. All of the files have the write and execute bit set for user, group and other. The execute bit is not set in the Windows permissions.

I have been using this command on an openSUSE install successfully. When mounted on that distro the files reflect the actual Windows permissions and do not all have the execute bit set. Furthermore, I am able to change the permissions using chmod.

(Note, I am running the Linux installs in VMware Workstation 8.0.3).

Kubuntu 12.04 64-Bit:

```
Linux Hostname 3.2.0-24-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 25 08:43:22 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.
```

openSUSE 12.1 64-Bit:

```
Linux Hostname 3.1.10-1.9-desktop #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Apr 5 18:48:38 UTC 2012 (4a97ec8) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I think the kernel option CONFIG_CIFS_ACL is needed but is not set in the default kernel. I am investigation this option now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For proper ACL support, you need to compile a custom kernel with the `CONFIG_CIFS_ACL` option enabled. As of 12.04 this is not set by default